# Data not pulling through to form - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to pull data from a form and as per my screenshot below the data will not display, but it appears to be functioning to a certain extent as there are two users which exist in my instructor variable and there are two options to select from, can anyone help?

[image]

create.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Create Course</div>
                <div class="card-body">

                        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('admin.courses.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            @csrf

                            <div class="form-group">
                                    @if (Auth::user()->isAdmin())
                                            {!! Form::label('Instructor', 'Instructor', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
                                            {!! Form::select('Instructor[]', $Instructor, Input::get('Instructor'), ['class' => 'form-control select2', 'multiple' => 'multiple']) !!} 
                                            @if($errors->has('Instructor'))
                                                <p class="help-block">
                                                    {{ $errors->first('Instructor') }}
                                                </p>
                                            @endif
                                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="required" for="name">Course Title</label>
                                <input class="form-control {{ $errors->has('title') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" type="text" name="title" id="id" value="{{ old('title', '') }}" required>
                                @if($errors->has('name'))
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    {{ $errors->first('name') }}
                                </div>
                            @endif
                         </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">
                                Save
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                     @endif
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            @endsection
```

CoursesController

```
  protected function create()
    {
        {
            $Instructor = \App\User::whereHas('role', function ($q) { $q->where('role_id', 2); } )->get()->pluck('title', 'id');

            // $courses = Course::all()->pluck('title');

            return view('admin.courses.create', compact('Instructor'));
        }
    }
```

User.php

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{

protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

public function role()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'role_user');
    }


    public function isAdmin()
    {
        return $this->role()->where('role_id', 1)->first();
    }

    public function roles(){


           return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role'); 
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: dd($Instructor) in your create method check data is there or not?

Comment: @umefarooq apologies if this is a silly question but how do i do this? I am new to laravel. Do I need this in a method or comment out my other code and run it alone?

Comment: yes you need to in controller create method to debug data

Comment: @umefarooq it returns undefined variable: instructor

Comment: I am not sure I completely understand -- you are pulling data from your form into the scope of the application? Or pulling data from the application and putting it into the view?

Answer (score 2):

The Laravel Collective `Form::select` requires the values to be in a `[ key => value ]` array pair. You are passing it a result collection.

You need to translate the result of `$Instructor = \App\User::whereHas('role', function ($q) { $q->where('role_id', 2); } )->get()->pluck('title', 'id');` to an array that is (I assume) `[ id => title, id => title ]`...

So, before you pass it to your view something like this:

```php
$flatInstructors = []
$Instructor->each(function($item, $key) {
   $flatInstructors[$item->id] = $item->title;
});

return view('admin.courses.create', compact('flatInstructors'));
```

And use `$flatInstructors` in your `Form::select` generation.

Comment: You are doing same thing in .each loop what pluck will return you. so no need to repeat again

Comment: It is not the same.